# What is the next short word in this long sequence?

Tags: knowledge, pattern, sequence, word-sequence

Which *one* of the four answers fits the word sequence below and why?

> Am
>
> As
>
> On
>
> An
>
> Or
>
> Or
>
> On
>
> ?

Four choices:   1. At  2. Or 3. Law  4. Over

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A justifiable word is

> Law - as it's incorporated in De**law**are

The list has the pattern of

> US states in alphabetical order:
>  Alab**am**a
>  Al**as**ka
>  Ariz**on**a
>  Ark**an**sas
>  Calif**or**nia
>  Col**or**ado
>  C**on**necticut